# How to solve CORS error in React and Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors

I am using React in the frontend and node/express server in the backend and the project worked fine before but now i am getting a CORS error

Access to fetch at 'https://dry-reef-22080.herokuapp.com/imageUrl' from origin 'https://smart-brain-04.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

I tried adding the mode and headers in the frontend

```
fetch(`https://dry-reef-22080.herokuapp.com/imageUrl`, {
      method: "post",
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        input: this.state.input
      })
    })
```

I access a another external api called clarifail in the backend

```
const Clarifai = require('clarifai');

const app = new Clarifai.App({
    apiKey: 'XYZ'
   });

const handleImageUrl = (req, res) => {
   app.models.predict(
    'c0c0ac362b03416da06ab3fa36fb58e3',
    req.body.input)
    .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
    })
   }
```

i also tried to use the npm package cors but the problem still persists

```
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');

const Register = require('./Controllers/Register');
const signin = require('./Controllers/signin');
const profileget = require('./Controllers/profileget');
const image = require('./Controllers/image');

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0

const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ssl: true
    }
  });

const app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: `no-cors` likely does not what you want.  I [wrote a blogpost](https://evertpot.com/no-cors/) about this. So, remove `no-cors` and share what error appears in the console.

Comment: This is the Error:--

Access to fetch at 'https://dry-reef-22080.herokuapp.com/imageUrl' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: if `dry-reef-22080.herokuapp.com` is yours, you need to add CORS config, if it isn't yours, then you need to access it via your server, not through the client

Comment: also, don't add response headers as request headers ... `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header and does not belong in a request

Comment: yes dry-reef-22080.herokuapp.com is my server which i deployed to heroku

Answer (score -1):

Try this set the mode from fetch to cors, since you are using the cors npm module in your backend you should also use cors for your request going to the backend.
It should look somewhat like this:

```
fetch(`https://dry-reef-22080.herokuapp.com/imageUrl`, {
  method: "post",
  mode: "cors",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    input: this.state.input
  })
})
```